# PDF structure graphical representation: display the proportion of each section in the final pdf file

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents

When I write a paper with a fixed page limit, I often want to see which section takes too much space so that I can move it to appendix. To that end, I would like to have a graphical representation of my pdf. The most basic thing I would like to have is a graph representing the proportion of each section (including the references), and making clear where is the page limit and where is the current transition between main paper and appendix. If possible, I'd love to be more precise than page number, to avoid thinking that a section takes one more pages just because it started at the end of a page.

I'd love to have this information displayed directly on each page of my pdf, for instance using an overlay in the footer of every page, but I'm also fine with using an external tool to visualize it.

**BONUS:** Another great tool to help to visualize my pdf would be to list the definitions and theorems from the preliminary section which are never used in the main paper (sometimes, when I move a proof in the appendix, I don't need to introduce the concept in the introduction). Graphically, it could either be represented via a list of labels, or an interactive web page that displays each anchor and an arrow from each section that points to it...

**EDIT**:

I found a way to access to the page/position in page data using:

```
$ mutool show {your-pdf-file} outline
+       "Introduction"  #2,135,116
|               "Our Results"   #2,135,533
[...]
```

The format at the end is `#PAGE,X,Y` where `X` and `Y` are distance from top left corner, in UserUnit, which (by default) equals to 1/72 inch=2.54/72cm. I guess it's possible to use a parser to obtain similar results, I know there is a pdf parser directly inside LuaLaTeX, cf the `pdfe` library page 262 (for now) in the [LuaLaTeX manual](https://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/luatex.pdf). Not sure if it's possible to directly inspect `aux` files or similar to obtain these information: for now I can find the page grepping `newlabels`, but not the X/Y position. Also, we need to find the start/end of the text body for these number to be more useful.